# Is there a way to rename file names in a folder by matching an Excel file column?

Tags: python, excel, rename

Example would be I have a file PDF and it's just John Smith. In the Excel file I have John Smith and in another column John Smith's Tax ID number. How do I get John Smith 5555555? Would like to rename all file names from matching the name in an Excel file.def rename_file(file_to_rename, source_file):

```
def rename_file(file_to_rename, source_file):
p = Path('C:\Users\Chris\Box\Capital\Fund, 2 L.P\Tax')
filename = p.stem
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\Users\Chris\Box\Capital\Fund, 2 L.P\Tax\Fund 2 LP - Document Uploader ID 2021')
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

for row_num in range(sheet.nrows):
    row_value = sheet.row_values(row_num)
    col = 4 # 'john smith' col number
    if row_value[col] == filename:
        new_filename = f'{row_value[col]}_{row_value[col - 1]}'  # format as you want
        p.rename(Path(p.parent, new_filename + p.suffix))  # rename
        break

def get_paths_in_directory(directory):
    return Path(directory).glob('*.pdf')

if __name__ == "__main__":

source_file = "Fund 2 LP - Document Uploader ID 2021.xlsx" # excel file to get new filename
source_directory = "C:\Users\Chris\Box\Capital\Fund, 2 L.P\Tax\2021 Final" # directory where your files to rename are.

# iterate all pdf files in the given directory
paths = get_paths_in_directory(source_directory)
for file_to_rename in paths:
    rename_file(str(file_to_rename), source_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work. (You need to pip install the packages)

```py
import xlrd
from pathlib import Path


def rename_file(file_to_rename, source_file):
    p = Path(file_to_rename)
    filename = p.stem
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(source_file)
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

    for row_num in range(sheet.nrows):
        row_value = sheet.row_values(row_num)
        col = 0 # 'john smith' col number
        if row_value[col] == filename:
            new_filename = f'{row_value[col]}_{row_value[col + 1]}'  # format as you want
            p.rename(Path(p.parent, new_filename + p.suffix))  # rename
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # add iteration to rename multiple files
    file_to_rename = "john.pdf"
    source_file = "new_names.xlsx"
    rename_file(file_to_rename, source_file)
```

You can add iteration if you want to rename multiple files.
Hope this helps!

--

#### Edit

Since you asked for more details, I'll add a simple iteration example.

```py
import xlrd
from pathlib import Path


def rename_file(file_to_rename, source_file):
    p = Path(file_to_rename)
    filename = p.stem
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(source_file)
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

    for row_num in range(sheet.nrows):
        row_value = sheet.row_values(row_num)
        col = 0 # 'john smith' col number
        if row_value[col] == filename:
            new_filename = f'{row_value[col]}_{row_value[col + 1]}'  # format as you want
            p.rename(Path(p.parent, new_filename + p.suffix))  # rename
            break

def get_paths_in_directory(directory):
    return Path(directory).glob('*.pdf')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    source_file = "new_names.xlsx" # excel file to get new filename
    source_directory = "files_to_rename" # directory where your files to rename are.
    
    # iterate all pdf files in the given directory
    paths = get_paths_in_directory(source_directory)
    for file_to_rename in paths:
        rename_file(str(file_to_rename), source_file)
```

And, of course, create your script file (e.g. 'rename_files.py'), copy and paste this code, and run it by `python3 rename_files.py`

let me know if you got more questions.

Comment: Hi Seoul, I need to rename multiple file names, can you show how I add the iteration?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what to do with this code, if you can provide more details and steps on how I can integrate/implement it please?

Comment: @ShreddedScientist okay, i'll add iteration example for you.

Comment: @ShreddedScientist just added another example script. hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Seoul, I've added my file paths and Excel file name in the variables, does this make sense? Not sure if p = Path('C:\Users\Chris\Box\Capital\Fund, 2 L.P\Tax') is correct, please see my edits to my question, many thanks.  Also what do I put in this variable? def get_paths_in_directory(directory):